# JSON response for empty params

Tags: node.js, json, api, express, backend

I need a specific o/p if i get empty params. But i was getting a "Cannot Get ... " .

1. This is what i was doing:

```
   app.get("/api/timestamp/:date", function(req, res) 

   {
     let dateString = req.params.date;

   ...(some code here)

   // empty params

   if(!req.params.date) {
    res.json({...});
   
   };});
```

2. This seems to solve the issue"

```
   app.get("/api/timestamp/", function(req, res) {
     res.json({...});
   });
```

I dont understand why 1 didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use optional param add `?` after date ,this won't throw can't get this route error

```
app.get("/api/timestamp/:date?", function(req, res) 

   {
     let dateString = req.params.date;

   ...(some code here)

   // empty params

   if(!req.params.date) {
    res.json({...});
   
   };});
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated :)